# How to calculate gate charge time for a mosfet?

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, charge

[image]

I am designing the circuit shown above using mosfet [NDS355AN](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2286073.pdf). MCU is 5 V.
However, I have become stuck as I am unsure of how to calculate the gate charge time of the mosfet. Hence what is the formula to calculate the charge time for the gate of the mosfet?

**Is it just essentially tau = RC = 1500 * Ciss?**

Note LED contains resistor inside (is a very large all in one)

Comment: Calculating gate charge time misses the point - you probably want to know how long it takes to reach an adequate gate-source voltage for the MOSFET to be reasonably conducting.

Comment: What currents do you expect the FET to handle? and how much delta_V do you expect on the drain? The charging of drain-gate capacitance (Miller Capacitance) may define your speed.

Comment: @Andy aka how would I do that then?

Comment: @analogsystemrf, gate current would be 3.33 mA, LED current is 30 mA

Comment: Again you didn't draw a current limiting resistor for the LED. As a typical beginner, you think anything is an issue including gate charge time. Just do the calculation, how long does it take the 200 pF gate capacitance (ignore the gate-drain cap just now) when using a 1.5 k resistor? Is that time constant relevant when compared to the signal that the MCU will generate?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie check the update regarding the LED.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I know its not an issue, I am just wanting to know how to calculate it as I am unsure

Comment: If the charge time is relevant, you should also take R2 into account!

Comment: @Huisman I know as that was the case in OP's previous question. That does not change the point that the resistor should be visible in the schematic. Inaccurate schematics nearly always lead to confusion. At least, that's my opinion.

Comment: @Huisman wouldn't R2 be negligible as its 1 million ohms and so wouldn't have much of an effect?

Comment: Couldn't read it clearly. You're right that 1M\$ \Omega\$ will have almost no effect.

Comment: @Huisman , do you know  to calculate how long it takes to reach an adequate gate-source voltage for the MOSFET to be reasonably conducting?

Comment: Instead of asking **do the calculation and prove it**. What would you use as proof if your professor says: "The 1 M ohm resistor has an effect". A simple "no it doesn't" does not convince the Prof. Also, I could read that resistor as being 1 n ohm (1 nano ohm, 1E10^-9 ohm or 1 milli ohm). For Mega use "M" so 1 M ohm.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie this is not a question for a subject, it is just for my understanding. I am just wanting to know what the equations are to calculate what I asked and possibly know  how long it takes to reach an adequate gate-source voltage for the MOSFET to be reasonably conducting since I assume they are pretty standard formulas ( i just couldn't find them online)

Comment: Instead of trying to define everything a circuit does using formulas, sit down for a minute and **think** what happens when the MOSFET is switched on. The MOSFET gate behaves as a capacitor. In the datasheet there's a value for that. You have a resistor that charges this capacitor. So this is **exactly the same** as charging a capacitor through a resistor. The equations for that can be found in many basic electronics books and courses. This RC model is a simplification as there is also a gate-drain capacitance and the drain changes voltage but first solve the simplified RC.

Comment: I think you also know it, you're not that way off. A) pick the "adequate gate-source voltage" based on drain source current (Figure 2 datasheet). B) Apply the equation for charging a capacitor and calculate what times it takes to reach the chosen Vgs, using R1 (and R2 if you like) and the voltage of the MCU's output.

Comment: Ciss = Cgs + Cdg

Answer (score 4):

[The step by step time constants](https://www.vishay.com/docs/73217/an608a.pdf)

[image]

I coloured zones for dynamic losses.

When using a driver with matched impedance to the gate resistance, Rg ;

- **During turn-on**  Ids almost peaks THEN Vds falls
- **During turn-off** Vds almost peaks THEN Ids falls.

  - during these dynamic switching times
  - Pd= Vds*Ids is greatest.

As once written, *seek and ye shall find*. 
or re-Search, next time DIY.

From your datasheet...

spec: VGS = 4.5V,  RGEN = 6 Ω  You are driving gate with 1k5 instead of 6 Ω , **so we use total Gate Charge equation and datasheet specs instead using worst case.**

**So effectively with a high source R you are driving with a current source Ig=Vgs/R 
 then  from $$ I_g = ΔQ_g/Δt_s , (ΔQ=Q) , Δt_s = Q_g/I_g = Q_gR_g/V_{gs} = 5nC_{max}\cdot 1k5/5V=1us$$**

Yet if we simply used **T=RC=1k5*195pf=293ns** (typ) (0.3us)  is only 30% typ of the more accurate worst case gate charge times.

The Miller plateau for a current source gate drive means that from  C=Q/V is Vgs is flat and Q jumps to the right, that means C rises until Vds drops to minimum. This is a negative feedback effect.

Comment: Thanks, so can tau = RC = 1500 * Ciss be used as a general rule or no?

Comment: Why don't you compute the formula and tell me the Vgs/Vth ratio that gives you a 10% error.

Comment: Sorry im just confused with what the total turn on time would be, is it t1 + t2 + t3?

Comment: which part is confusing?

Comment: just specifically what t1 t2 and t3 actually mean potentially. As in is t1 when the mosfet fully switches on as the threshold voltage is reached then? Then what does t2 and t3 refer to?

Comment: The VI curves and formula shows you what it means for t1,t2,t3 but that assumes you are driving with a voltage source with matched Rg.  But you are using a current source. right?

Comment: the mcu outputs 5 V @ the current limited by 1500 ohms

Comment: i think my issue is i have to research more into understanding what the v gate plateau is etc

Comment: Its the MIller effect where falling  Vds voltage negative feedback keeps Vgs constant while using a large Rg which acts as a current source.. Yet uC driver impedance is usually <50 Ohms